# What is the simplest way to execute a Java class every 30 seconds?

Tags: java, spring, jboss, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

I've been reading about java/spring/hibernate and worked trough a "dummy" examples so I told my friend to recommend something a bit harder for me, and now I'm stuck.. here is the simplest class I could think of

```
package spring.com.practice;

public class Pitcher {

    private String shout;

    public String getShout() {
        return shout;
    }

    public void setShout(String shout) {
        this.shout = shout;
    }

    public void voice()
    {
        System.out.println(getShout());
    }

}
```

What is the most simple way to print out something by calling metod `voice()` from spring beans, and do it repeadatly every 30 seconds lets say, here is what I've got so far :

```
<bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="jobSchedulerDetail" />
    <property name="startDelay" value="0" />
    <property name="repeatInterval" value="30" />
</bean>


<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="schedulerName" value="pitcherScheduler" />
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="simpleTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
 <bean id="pitcher" class="spring.com.practice.Pitcher">
 <property name="shout" value="I started executing..."></property>
 </bean>
```

And yes I'm trying to run this on Jboss 5, I'm building a project with maven.

I got some suggestions and my application context now looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:sched="http://www.springinaction.com/schema/sched"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springinaction.com/schema/sched
       http://www.springinaction.com/schema/sched-1.0.xsd"
       default-lazy-init="true">

   <bean id="stuffDoer" class="spring.com.practice">
   <property name="shout" value="I'm executing"/>
   </bean>

  <sched:timer-job
       target-bean="stuffDoer"
       target-method="voice"
       interval="5000" 
       start-delay="1000"
       repeat-count="10" />

</beans>
```

Here is my web.xml :

```
<web-app id="simple-webapp" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>spring app</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/conf/applicationContext.xml
</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Now I get this exeption :

```
12:35:51,657 ERROR [01-SNAPSHOT]] Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
```

I didn't realize executing something like hello world every 30 sec would be this complicated

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I wouldn't bother with Quartz, it's overkill for something this simple. Java5 comes with its own scheduler, and it's good enough.

Pre-Spring 3, this is was the easiest approach:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean">
    <property name="scheduledExecutorTasks">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorTask">
                <property name="period" value="30000"/>
                <property name="runnable">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.support.MethodInvokingRunnable">
                        <property name="targetObject" ref="pitcher"/>
                        <property name="targetMethod" value="voice"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

With Spring 3, it can be ridiculously easy:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate=30000)
public void voice() {
    System.out.println(getShout());
}
```

and

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
           "> 

  <bean id="pitcher" class="spring.com.practice.Pitcher">
     <property name="shout" value="I started executing..."></property>
  </bean>

  <task:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

Comment: That `@Scheduled` annotation looks really nice.

Comment: @skaffman thank you for your response, I'll try that now, the thing is I want to do something more complicated so I want to start from bottom up. `I want to create 2 objects that send messages to each other, one to greet other to respond trough JMS messaging on JBOSS 5, and I want this done every 30 seconds.` So first thing to consider would be the executing task every 30 seconds and then onwards ..

Comment: @skaffman Great answer, I tried it both ways and its working .. w00w tnx

Comment: @BalusC: It is quite tasty, I agree, but in practice you want to make the period configurable, and that's where the annotation doesn't work.

Comment: Hello skaffman, could you please explain how ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean is used then ? Or please take a look at this question I can't figure out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021766/spring-scheduled-threadpool-running-threads-with-parameters-supplied-different ... You seem to have a strong grasp of this

Answer (score 2):

With Spring 3, you can quickly use `@Scheduled` and `@Async` !

Check this out: [Implement @Scheduled in Spring Application](http://javaprogrammingtips4u.blogspot.com/2010/05/how-to-implement-task-scheduler-job.html)

Answer (score 1):

It looks complicated, but that really is the best way to do that. You can configure it external to the application, and let spring/quartz handle execution.

This is especially useful when the method you need to call is a transaction-enabled service call.

Comment: @Reverend Gonzo obviously there is something wrong with this .. I get no exeptions, and yet the quartz doesn't execute, copied war to jboss dir .. and still nothing, I created simple webapp hello world to chk is my jboss configured properly, yes it is.

Answer (score 1):

I have something similar but using the QuartzConnector class in mule, which runs every 20 seconds. See example. The other way would be to use the cron type time entry see [Quartz Cron](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorials/crontrigger.html)

```
    <endpoint name="poller" address="quartz://poller1" type="sender" connector="QuartzConnector">
      <properties>
        <property name="repeatInterval" value="20000"/>
        <property name="payloadClassName" value="org.jdom.Document" />
        <property name="startDelay" value="10000"/>                
      </properties>
    </endpoint>
```

Comment: @Wiretap thank you I'm really trying to learn spring and as much as possible about it, so I'd like to use springs quartz

Comment: Looks like this may be useful, as sounds like similar situation
http://www.jroller.com/habuma/entry/a_funny_thing_happened_while

Comment: It appears that up to now I didn't link my application context with web.xml here is the error I get now `12:35:51,657 ERROR [01-SNAPSHOT]] Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener` I'll update my question with appcontext

Answer (score 0):

you can use scheduled task

```
<bean id="EmptyScopesRemover" class="com.atypon.pagebuilder.core.tasks.impl.EmptyScopesRemoverImpl"/>

<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="EmptyScopesRemover" method="remove" cron="0 */1 * * * *"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

here is a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mt5R_KBlhTU

and you can check this answer to corn values
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32521238/4251431