# Spring - scheduling and pooling runnables of different state (each Runnable instance has different state)

Tags: spring, threadpool

I can't figure out what to use for scheduling and pooling runnables of different state (each Runnable instance has different state). I could use ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean together with MethodInvokingRunnable to supply arguments. But take a look at the key ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean method, it is designed in a way that all task should start at the beginning.

```
    protected void registerTasks(ScheduledExecutorTask[] tasks, ScheduledExecutorService executor) {
        for (ScheduledExecutorTask task : tasks) {
            Runnable runnable = getRunnableToSchedule(task);
            if (task.isOneTimeTask()) {
                executor.schedule(runnable, task.getDelay(), task.getTimeUnit());
            }
            else {
                if (task.isFixedRate()) {
                    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, task.getDelay(), task.getPeriod(), task.getTimeUnit());
                }
                else {
                    executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(runnable, task.getDelay(), task.getPeriod(), task.getTimeUnit());
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I can't think of how to setup this scenario with ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.

Please help me out here. Thank you

---

EDIT: shortened version is: how to setup task scheduler that would run hundreds of "different instances of Threads (with different state) with 2 seconds interval.

Comment: I thought that I could use AnnotationConfigApplicationContext to setup ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean with multiple ScheduledExecutorTasks each having MethodInvokingRunnable with different values of arguments supplied....Sounds ok to me

Comment: What I'm trying to do, is to schedule threads representing http get requests (each having different proxy and target) each starting few seconds after the previous, there are thousands of them, connections lasts up to 30 seconds so that I need it concurrent

Comment: Now I think that taskSchedulers are absolutely not supposed for what I wanna do. They are supposed for scheduling one immutable task / Runnable. Right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy, I don't know what I was thinking that I didn't see it :-)

---

I have just programmatically filled the array ScheduledExecutorTask[] of ScheduledExecutorFactoryBean with thousands of tasks, each with incremented delay property and different runnable. Then I just used the factorybean...Really handy factorybean from spring guys...